# How do I get ORACLE JAVA SE 7 to work?

Tags: 13.04, java, software-installation, jdk, oracle

I am a newbie to Ubuntu, so kindly be considerate.

I recently manually downloaded & installed (Java SE 7ux) JavaSE 1.7.0_51. 
Linux x64 (for 64-bit system) "tar.gz" package. 
My Ubuntu version is 13.10  (OS 64 bit)

I carefully following the instructions from: [How to Install JDK 7 on Ubuntu](http://www3.ntu.edu.sg/home/ehchua/programming/howto/Ubuntu_HowTo.html#jdk)

*To verify that the installation was successful I wrote:*

```
javac -version
```

and get the below results:

```
Error occurred during initialization of VM
java/lang/NoClassDefFoundError: java/lang/Object

$ which java gives the below results:  
/usr/bin/java

$ which javac also gives the below results:
/usr/bin/javac
```

I repeated the steps a couple of times just in case I missed out an important step but still got the same results. After a couple of researching on-line I found out @ [Reference](http://www.webupd8.org/2012/01/install-oracle-java-jdk-7-in-ubuntu-via.html), that I could actually install Java on Ubuntu via PPA repository.

After the installation when I

```
$ java -version
```

I still get:

```
Error occurred during initialization of VM
java/lang/NoClassDefFoundError: java/lang/Object
```

However when I

```
$ cd /usr/bin
$ ls -ld java*
```

I get:

```
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 22 Feb 19 19:06 java -> /etc/alternatives/java
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 23 Feb 17 02:15 javac -> /etc/alternatives/javac
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 25 Feb 19 20:09 javadoc -> /etc/alternatives/javadoc
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 32 Feb 19 20:09 javafxpackager -> /etc/alternatives/javafxpackager
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 23 Feb 19 20:09 javah -> /etc/alternatives/javah
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 23 Feb 19 20:09 javap -> /etc/alternatives/javap
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 25 Feb 19 20:09 java_vm -> /etc/alternatives/java_vm
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 24 Feb 17 02:15 javaws -> /etc/alternatives/javaws
```

Also similar to:

```
$ cd /etc/alternatives 
$ ls -ld java*

lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 36 Feb 19 19:15 java -> /usr/local/java/jdk1.7.0_51/bin/java
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 37 Feb 17 02:15 javac -> /usr/local/java/jdk1.7.0_51/bin/javac
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 38 Feb 19 20:09 javadoc -> /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-oracle/bin/javadoc
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 48 Feb 19 20:09 javadoc.1.gz -> /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-oracle/man/man1/javadoc.1.gz
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 45 Feb 19 20:09 javafxpackager -> /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-oracle/bin/javafxpackager
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 55 Feb 19 20:09 javafxpackager.1.gz -> /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-oracle/man/man1/javafxpackager.1.gz
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 36 Feb 19 20:09 javah -> /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-oracle/bin/javah
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 46 Feb 19 20:09 javah.1.gz -> /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-oracle/man/man1/javah.1.gz
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 36 Feb 19 20:09 javap -> /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-oracle/bin/javap
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 46 Feb 19 20:09 javap.1.gz -> /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-oracle/man/man1/javap.1.gz
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 42 Feb 19 20:09 java_vm -> /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-oracle/jre/bin/java_vm
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 42 Feb 17 02:15 javaws -> /usr/local/java/jdk1.7.0_51/jre/bin/javaws
```

Note that

```
javadoc.1.gz -> /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-oracle/man/man1/javadoc.1.gz
javafxpackager.1.gz -> /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-oracle/man/man1/javafxpackager.1.gz
javah.1.gz -> /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-oracle/man/man1/javah.1.gz
javah.1.gz -> /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-oracle/man/man1/javah.1.gz
```

...are all in RED

- What does all this mean and most importantly how do I make my Java installation work?

Looking forward to you help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Download the Oracle java from its offical website

[Download Java From Official website Here](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/index.html)

Manually Install the JDK 1.7

```
#java -version

#sudo mkdir -p /usr/lib/jvm

#sudo mv jdk-7u21-linux-i586.tar.gz /usr/lib/jvm

#cd /usr/lib/jvm

#sudo tar zxvf jdk-7u21-linux-i586.tar.gz

#sudo rm jdk-7u21-linux-i586.tar.gz

#ls -l

#jdk1.7.0_21

#sudo update-alternatives --install "/usr/bin/javac" "javac" "/usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.7.0_21/bin/javac" 1

#sudo update-alternatives --install "/usr/bin/java" "java" "/usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.7.0_21/bin/java" 1

#sudo update-alternatives --set "javac" "/usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.7.0_21/bin/javac"

#sudo update-alternatives --set "java" "/usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.7.0_21/bin/java"

#sudo vi /etc/profile

Add the following entries to the bottom of your /etc/profile file:

#JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.7.0_21 PATH=$PATH:$JAVA_HOME/bin export JAVA_HOME export PATH

#. /etc/profile

#java -version
```

Replace the jdk1.7.0_21 With the version u have Downloaded

Comment: Dont I have to un-install the currently installed Java first?

Comment: Remove it Using 
# sudo apt-get remove java*

Comment: sudo apt-get remove java* messed up my system. Alot of applications ubuntu disappeared, so I am working on reinstalling  alot of them back. But  Thanks the solution worked!

Comment: Do you know how to install J2ME Developmental Kit on Ubuntu?

Comment: If Some other Program messed up after installing above, Just do # suso apt-get install java*

Comment: Could you please share the steps to reverse it all you mentioned above