# How to update Java version to 7 or 8 using the ppa link ?

Tags: 14.04, java, ppa

I have already tried to:

1. Re-install ca certificates
2. Run: `sudo -E apt-add-repository`
3. Add repository links to the `etc/apt/sources.list` manually.

None of the above worked. I am trying to run IGV Browser in my system (Ubuntu 14.04 Trusty Tahr). Kindly help.

Comment: Are you upgrading from Existing version ?

Comment: Could you please have a look at here http://askubuntu.com/questions/423558/how-do-i-get-oracle-java-se-7-to-work/423559#423559  to get fix your issue @Hasanahana

Answer (score 0):

Download the Oracle java from its offical website

[Download Java From Official website Here](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/index.html)

Download this

```
Linux x64   151.64 MB     jdk-8u5-linux-x64.tar.gz
```

Manually Install the JDK

```
#java -version

#sudo mkdir -p /usr/lib/jvm

#sudo mv jdk-8u5-linux-x64.tar.gz /usr/lib/jvm

#cd /usr/lib/jvm

#sudo tar zxvf jdk-8u5-linux-x64.tar.gz

#sudo rm jdk-8u5-linux-x64.tar.gz

#ls -l

#jdk8.5

#sudo update-alternatives --install "/usr/bin/javac" "javac" "/usr/lib/jvm/jdk8.5/bin/javac" 1

#sudo update-alternatives --install "/usr/bin/java" "java" "/usr/lib/jvm/jdk8.5/bin/java" 1

#sudo update-alternatives --set "javac" "/usr/lib/jvm/jdk8.5/bin/javac"

#sudo update-alternatives --set "java" "/usr/lib/jvm/jdk8.5/bin/java"

#sudo vi /etc/profile

Add the following entries to the bottom of your /etc/profile file:

#JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/jdk8.5 PATH=$PATH:$JAVA_HOME/bin export JAVA_HOME export PATH

#. /etc/profile

#java -version
```

Replace the jdk8.5 With the version you have Downloaded